# Please help with an appropriate type of regression to obtain numerical result (SPSS) with categorical data

Tags: regression, categorical-data, spss

Please help me to figure out the right approach for fairly straightforward task.

Let say, we asked respondents to state 3 most important attributes (over ten) for the one product. Answers were coded in 3 columns.
Then we asked to generally evaluate product on 5-point Likert scale. (Like/Dislike product).

How to learn which attributes really lead to the higher evaluation and in which direction?

Extra question - what if respondents not just state 3 most important factors but rate them. How to incorporate this information (that I can't figure out at all...)

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Regarding categorical regression. Do you mean, apply CATREG to the same dichotomous multiple response set and treat every response (1,0) as categorical?    For the "important" attribute. Yes, it's the same importance. In basic frequency calculation it should somehow weight final result. In regression, I guess it should somehow weight every response.

Comment: 1) A dichotomous predictor behaves identically when it is treated as a "continuous" predictor and when treated as categorical factor. 2) If the rating is the importance then it is simple: appoint "not selected" attribute value importance=0, the lowest rating point. Please be aware that CATREG does not allow 0 value; so add 1 to all the values to make the lowest code 1.

Comment: I turned my comments into an answer and deleted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your independent variables, the attributes, constitute 10 binary variables with values 1 (selected, important) and 0 (not selected, unimportant). So, recode your 'categorical multiple response set' (3 columns with attributes' codes) into that 'dichotomous multiple response set', and go on.

Regarding the choice of regression. If you dare to take the likert dependent variable an interval one use **linear** regression. If you take it as ordinal one use **ordinal** regression. You can also use **categorical** regression (CATREG) which transforms categorical data into interval nonlinearly (so called "optimal scaling") in order to maximize the prediction by a linear model and then performs that linear regression.

Possible answers to your last paragraph depend on whether the rating of an "important" attribute is the importance again or is a different characteristic.

**Update** for the last: Since in your comment you indicate that the rating is the importance, then it is simple - because the rating then is the same process as selecting to be important/unimportant. Appoint "not selected" attribute value importance=0, the lowest rating point (of, say, rating scale 1-5): you get rating scale 0-5. This action clearly leaves the scale ordinal and not interval - because you don't know whether the diastema between ratings 0 and 1 is the same as between 1 and 2. This naturally calls you to use categorical regression, as the regression which can use ordinal predictors by "optimally" converting them into interval ones. (Please be aware that CATREG does not allow 0 value; so add 1 to all the values to make the lowest code 1.)

Another strategy to incorporate ordinal predictors in regression is to investigate them as giving polynomial effects (e.g., for example, add a squared copy of every predictor to the regression model).

Comment: I'm sorry I probably misexplained importance factor. Currently, respondents just place check mark against attributes. I think to replace checkmark with rank. So, I don't want to make evaluating every attribute on separate scale but rank them directly. That is, currently respondents choose 3 most important attributes as 1,1,1. I want to replace it on 1,2,3

Comment: So, you say that people select the three attributes and rank them. But that is exactly the same thing as rating by _ordinal_ scale: `0=not selected=unimportant at all, 1=least important, 2=medium important, 3=most important`. So, again: recode the 3 variables into the 10, if you want to use them as predictors.

Comment: ...Николай, before an analysis, feel free to recode and restructure your data to the view approprite for the analysis. Data may be collected (questionnaire) and entered (data file structure) in some convenient way which isn't necessarily the same way which is convenient for a specific analysis. In particularly, recoding between two types of multiple response structures (the dichotomous and the categorical) is everyday routine in marketing research.

Comment: Great, thank you! ttnphns, I'm not sure if it's possible to leave personal messages on this site and rivita seems doesn't work. Could you follow web site in my profile and drop me a message?